# Bounding exponential sums

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sum

There is classical inequality that seems to often appear:
$$\sum_{i=1}^N \exp(2i\pi n \theta) \leq \|\theta\|^{-1}$$
where $\|\theta\|$ denotes the distance to the closest integer. I do understand that it can be proven by writing a sum of geometric sequence, and then using Euler's formula to get that it is bounded by $2/\sin(\pi \theta)$, but then I do not see that easily the relation with $\|\theta\|$.

Comment: did you see my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the sum is even periodic function of $\theta$ with period 1. So it is enough to prove the estimate for $\theta \in [0,1/2].$ Over this interval $\sin(\pi \theta)/2$ majorizes the distance to the origin, i.e., $\| \theta \|:$

So, we have
$$
\|\theta\| \leq  \frac{\sin(\pi \theta)}{2}.
$$
Now take reciprocals.